# Resolving dependencies on the openuse build system

Tags: ubuntu, build, opensuse

My package builds on most of my target distros but Ubuntu 13.04 fails because they moved libgps-dev and libhamlib-dev to Universe and the OBS doesn't import Universe.

I have hamlib and gpsd projects in my repository and they build for Ubuntu 13.04. I thought this would automatically make them available to other projects in the same repository.

If I use link or aggregate to reference them it seems to be global across all distros and I get duplicate errors for the distros that have the packages.

Any ideas?

Project is here: http://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:juliancable/dream

Answer (score 0):

OK, the instructions did give me the part of answer. I had to take the dependencies out of the debian.control file AND out of the dsc file. I think this leaves the repository missing runtime dependency declarations but at least the package builds.